# How do I change the caret-color in an AceEditor theme?

Tags: ace-editor

How do I change the caret color in AceEditor? My theme makes the caret (the little blinking line where next character will type) nearly invisible. CSS offers caret-color but even if I add:

```
caret-color:white
```

to the CSS (either via the theme or directly into the CSS of the webpage) the AceEditor caret color remains the same. Direct CSS works fine for normal text inputs, just not AceEditor.

What's the correct way to change AceEditor's caret color? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ace Editor calls the caret a "cursor". Thus, the CSS style in the CSS theme is:

```
.ace_cursor {
    color:white
}
```

Just set the color to whatever color you want.